# Scrapy catch None response. AssertionError: Received None in process_response

Tags: python, scrapy, response

Scrapy 1.3.3. Sometimes happened response is None.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/vetos/venvs/aliber/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1301, in _inlineCallbacks
>       result = g.send(result)
>
> File "/home/vetos/venvs/aliber/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 47, in process_response
>
> assert response is not None, 'Received None in process_response'
>
> AssertionError: Received None in process_response

I have a  middleware:

```
class CustomProcessProxyResponse(object):
EXCEPTIONS_TO_RETRY = (defer.TimeoutError, TimeoutError, DNSLookupError,
                       ConnectionRefusedError, ConnectionDone, ConnectError,
                       ConnectionLost, TCPTimedOutError, ResponseFailed,
                       IOError, TunnelError)
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504, 408, 403, 401, 400, 404, 408]

def __init__(self, settings):
    pass

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    return cls(crawler.settings)

def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    if response is None:
        reason = ('Response is None; Request {}'.format(request))
        return self._retry(request, reason, spider) or response
    if response.status in self.RETRY_HTTP_CODES:
        reason = response_status_message(response.status)
        return self._retry(request, reason, spider) or response
    return response

def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
    return self._retry(request, exception, spider)

def _retry(self, request, reason, spider):
    proxy = request.meta['proxy']
    logger.debug("Gave up fail %(request)s (failed %(proxy)s ): %(reason)s",
                 {'request': request, 'proxy': proxy, 'reason': reason},
                 extra={'spider': spider})
    ProxyManager().remove_from_databаse(proxy)
    retryreq = request.copy()
    retryreq.dont_filter = True
    retryreq.productId = request.productId
    return retryreq
```

settings.py:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'aliexpress_affiliate_api.middlewares.CustomProxyMiddleware': 100,
'aliexpress_affiliate_api.middlewares.CustomProcessProxyResponse': 990,}


class CustomProxyMiddleware(object):
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    if spider.name == AliProductDetailExtender.name:
        proxy_manager = ProxyManager()
        proxy_server, country = proxy_manager.get_random_proxy_from_database()
        request.meta['proxy'] = proxy_server
        request.meta['proxy_country'] = country
        print(request.meta['proxy'])
```

errors interception and retrying requests is performed but sometimes occurs this error . How to intercept the answer when it is **None**?

Comment: You need to find what component is returning `None` in its `process_response`. This is not supposed to happen and Scrapy engine complains about it. Could it be your other custom middleware, `CustomProxyMiddleware` returning `None` in some cases in its `process_response`?

Comment: CustomProcessProxyResponse priority  is 990. In my opinion it should  first to intercept the response in its method process_response. As I understood from the documentation
[link](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#topics-downloader-middleway).  _In other words, the process_request() method of each middleware will be invoked in increasing middleware order (100, 200, 300, ...) and the process_response() method of each middleware will be invoked in decreasing order._

Comment: in DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES_BASE most  priority is 900

Comment: Correct. But what if `CustomProcessProxyResponse.process_response()` works fine and returns a `Response` and then `CustomProxyMiddleware.process_response` returns `None`? Scrapy will complain. You are not showing what `CustomProxyMiddleware` does, so we cannot tell. Anyhow, you may need a debugger for this in the end. As far as I know, Scrapy's engine and builtin components will not send `None` to a dowloader middleware as response.

Comment: add code 'CustomProxyMiddleware'. method `process_response` not implemented.  I think `CustomProxyMiddleware` should not affect on response.

Comment: Then I don't know. I suggest that you use a debugger to inspect why you are getting a `None` response.